# puppetlab 'file_line' type not working in one puppet apply run

Tags: puppet

When i run puppet apply policy1.pp , it does not apply all the file_line resource type written in policy1.pp. So when i run again puppet apply policy1.pp it will apply remaining file_line resource written in policy1.pp.

why this behaviour? Can't puppet apply all the resources in one run. This does not happen if it is file resource.

Comment: Please show some code or nobody can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

That happens to me as well. I kicked puppet and it seems to apply all the configuration, except file_line and it still won't apply it in every run until I manually will kick puppet agent for the second time.

```
# puppet pluginsync=true
file { "/etc/puppet/puppet.conf":
   mode => 644,
   owner => root,
   group => root,
   source => "puppet:///modules/linuxstandard/puppet.conf.ic3",
}
# Turn off local resolution, handled by do_userinstall.sh
#file_line { 'dnsmasqoff':
#  notify => Service["network-manager"],
#  path => '/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf',
#  match => 'dns=dnsmasq',
#  line => '#dns=dnsmasq',
#  require => File['/etc/puppet/puppet.conf'],
#}
file_line { 'sshdns':
 notify => Service["ssh"],
 path => '/etc/ssh/sshd_config',
 line => 'UseDNS no',
 require => File["/etc/puppet/puppet.conf"],
}
```